# BigQuery - filtering without losing 'null' values

Tags: null, google-bigquery, contains

I try to filter a database but unluckily I lose the 'null' values either way:

The Sample looks like

```
Name | City | Sold
Nike | NYC  | 15
null | SFO  | 20
Mega | SEA  | 10
null | null | 8
nike | CHI  | 12
```

I try to look for the data without Nike in any way written but when I go for

```
Select ...
where not lower(Name) contains "nike"
```

but then I find only

> Mega | SEA | 10

and all the rows with *null* values for **Name** are gone as well.
How can I prevent their deletion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

```
select * from 
(select string(NULL) as name,'SFO' as city, 20 as sold),
(select 'Nike' as name,'NYC' as city, 15 as sold),
where not lower(name) contains 'nike2' or name is null
```

returns

```
+-----+------+------+------+---+
| Row | name | city | sold |   |
+-----+------+------+------+---+
|   1 | null | SFO  |   20 |   |
|   2 | Nike | NYC  |   15 |   |
+-----+------+------+------+---+
```